# AWS email service pagination token having inconsistent behavior InvalidNextTokenException

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, httprequest

Problem: When testing HTTP requests for completed API for AWS email service in Insomnia, I was receiving proper responses on pagination tokens. Pagination tokens consist of various symbols (numbers/letters/others). But when QA from my team decided to test that service, they were receiving `InvalidNextTokenException` error despite using fresh tokens that were given to them from previous requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Apparently, various software for testing HTTP requests (so far that I found were Intellij Idea and Postman) were mutating the token data, changing all `+` symbols to `' '` blank spacebars symbols, which caused `InvalidNextTokenException`. While testing using Insomnia resulted in expected behavior.